# Moving from ExpressJS apps to ElectronJS apps

Tags: node.js, electron

I'm trying to understand the transition from Web Apps in Nodejs with Express to making similar apps on the Desktop with ElectronJS.

The thing I can't understand is how you change a view, for instance in Express if I have a basic CRUD app I have an `index` controller and view and a `create` *thing* controller and view, and I can switch between them my clicking links renders in the browser via Express.

How does that work in ElectronJS?

Am I supposed to run Express within Election? Is Electron somehow the Routing framework.. or do I have to drop that way of thinking all-together and use something like AngularJS or ReactJS?

Answer (score 0):

You have to understand why we use `express` first. It's a server that reads `http` requests which in ElectronJS doesn't make sense because you can directly communicate via `IPC`. So, no you don't run `express` in electron. And think of `electron` as a packaged `nodejs` that ships with your app. It's not a routing framework or anything. It's literally `nodejs` but with the ability to talk to Chromium as it's view where you can write HTML, CSS etc.
And lastly, yes, you can use whatever client library/framework that you'd use on your web app in `electron` too.